# Get cardview data to another activity with swipe

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data of card on right swipe and on left i want to remove it from list but not to delete it from firebase how can i achieve it ? Here is my code

```
  @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            if(direction==ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
            {
                Toast.makeText(home.this,      uplodinfo2.getBreed() +"/"+ uplodinfo2.getPrice()+"Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            if(direction==ItemTouchHelper.LEFT)
            {




            }
        }


    };

  protected void onStart()
    { super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PetData,PetAdapter> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PetData, PetAdapter>(PetData.class,R.layout.swipelayout,PetAdapter.class,query) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PetAdapter categoryviewHoder, final PetData uplodinfo, int i) {
                uplodinfo2=uplodinfo;
                categoryviewHoder.setDetail(getApplicationContext(),"Price: " + uplodinfo.getPrice() + "$","Breed Name: "+uplodinfo.getBreed(),uplodinfo.getImageUrl());
                       msg=  uplodinfo.getName();
                    //   txtcat.setText(Category);




                categoryviewHoder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(home.this,rightview.class);
                        startActivity(i);


                    }
                });
            }


        };
        recyclerHome.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code? What exactly doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I need to get data on new activity when i swipe a card

Comment: And when you swipe, what is happening now?

Comment: I'm not getting the desired result i equaled  uplodinfo2=uplodinfo but when i accessed uploadinfo2 data I'm getting the next cards data